# Is there any example of crowdsale contract of EOS?

Tags: smart-contract

It should be possible to run crowdsales on EOS blockchain, but I can't find any example or even reference. Is there any example?

Comment: Kind of, but that question doesn't have a proper answer anyway.

Comment: Please try to add comments to that question, e.g. ask for what is missing in the answer for you.